# Display multilingual error messages

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii framework to develop a multilingual web site. Right now I have English and French versions. I have created a `fr` folder and placed views and controllers related to French version, but using same models for both versions.

My database tables structure (articles table) is:

```
 id, title_en, title_fr, title_ru, detail_en, detail_fr, detail_ru and     
 so on.
```

The issue I am facing is that I need to display error messages to the users in respective languages like in French version error message should be in French. How can I do while using same model for all languages.

Where do I need to put the French messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `CPhpMessageSource::loadMessages()` with something like following:

```
protected function loadMessages($category,$language)
{
    if ($category == 'yii') 
        return array();
    else
        return parent::loadMessages($category,$language);
}
```

Also You can  change the language, set `CApplication::language` appropriately. This can be done at runtime as in

```
Yii::app()->language = 'fr';
```

Comment: The last line Yii::app()->language = 'fr'; worked. I only added  this line in controller's Action and it worked like a magic. all messages appeard in desired lannguage

Comment: @MazIqbal No need for both.only one is enough.

Comment: @Harikrishnan Why you're proposing overriding base class with some unnecessary code, if translation is provided by core framework? None of your answer is required, except setting application language -- as OP said in comment. As written in Yii1 docs, all you need to do is to provide proper messages and set language.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if I'm getting you correct, but if I understand your question, your problem is already solved by core Yii 1.x engine and there isn't much work left to do.

In detail, you have to:

1. Create any file (for example `app.php`) in `/protected/messages/fr/` folder.
2. Put `'coreMessages'=>array('basePath'=>'../protected/messages'),` to your application's configuration array -- route Yii translation system to folder with your customized translations.
3. Put `'sourceLanguage'=>'en'` to your configuration array -- make sure, that your applications's core language is set to English.
4. Fill `app.php` file with your translation strings (see below).
5. Translate parts of your application with `Yii::t('app', 'string');` (see below).

Your translation files should be in format:

```
return array
(
    //Translations from Google Translate! :> I don't speak French at all! :>
    'This page is not yet translated into your language.'=>'Cette page n'a pas encore été traduit dans votre langue.',
    'Language'=>'Langue',
    'read more'=>'en savoir plus'
);
```

So, for example, but in your blog list view string like:

```
<?php Yii::t('app', 'read more'); ?>
```

When you set your application language to `fr`, either by forcing it in code (`Yii::app()->language = 'fr';`) or presetting it in appliction's configuration array (`'language'=>'fr'`), you should see `en savoir plus` (or whatever you put to your translation file) in place of `read more` in above view.

If your application's language is set back to English or if given translation string is not found, you'll see text written in `Yii::t`. That's why it is so important to use fully qualified English strings in this method (and in translation files) and to avoid "patterns", like `'core.app.language'=>'Langue'` etc.

Note, that you can also use parameter placeholders:

```
'Error no {code}:'=>'Erreur n {code}:'
```

that will be replaced with the actual parameter values:

```
Yii::t('app', 'Error no {code}:', array('{code}'=>$code));
```

This way you can provide variable values to otherwise constant message text.

There's a great [topic about internationalization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n) in "The Definitive Guide to Yii". You should read it through for more information on this matter or, if you want to use Yii translation mechanism in a bit more advanced way.